# Upstream prematurely closed FastCGI stdout while reading response header from upstream

Tags: php, html, mysql, logging, nginx

I suddently get a 502 Bad gateway error and I don't understand why this error appear. This error appear moreover only for 1 single page!!...

The exact error in my Nginx log is :

```
 Upstream prematurely closed FastCGI stdout while reading response header from upstream [..] upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:"
```

I tried :

- service nginx restart : NOTHING CHANGE
- service php5-fpm restart : NOTHING CHANGE
- to reboot the server : NOTHING CHANGE
- even to restart the mysql service : NOTHING CHANGE

My /var/log/upstart/php5-fpm.log (only a lot of NOTICES) :

```
Terminating...
exiting, bye-bye!
fpm is running, pid 9887
ready to handle connections
systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
```

that makes me crazy, any idea ?

Comment: any solutions to this? It happens to me and didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

Strangely enough, this is what worked for me after chasing down a mysterious 502 Bad Gateway error:

- Change `error_reporting` setting in `php-fpm` ini like this:

  `error_reporting = ~E_ALL`
- Then restart `php-fpm` and `nginx`

This worked for me after trying the suggested nginx settings above to no avail. I don't have a verified explanation for this, but it would appear that excessive error reporting can overload the php-fpm process.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `include <fcgi_stdio.h>` in your source file.
This error happens to me just now,then i add `include <fcgi_stdio.h>`in my `c` file,here is my code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcgi_config.h>
#include <fcgi_stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    while(FCGI_Accept() >= 0)
    {
        printf("content-type:text/html\r\n");
        printf("\r\n");
        printf("<title>Fast CGI Hello</title>");
        printf("<h1>fast CGI hello</h1>");

        printf("Request number %d running on host<i>%s</i>\n",++count,getenv("SERVER_NAME"));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the error only for one type of requests that had 12 items in the body. May be it was related with a body size, but it worked when it was more (13 and more items) or some less (11 and less).

**upstream prematurely closed FastCGI stdout while reading response header from upstream**

```
2021/12/24 07:14:44 [error] 9#9: *49 upstream prematurely closed FastCGI stdout while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.21.0.1, server: , request: "PUT /v1/MY_PAGE/a976d2e5-afc0-4f6d-8d05-17af7dc73f46 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.21.0.3:9000", host: "localhost"
```

I used Docker containers with Nginx and PHP-FPM.

Nginx returned **502 Bad Gateway**.

[image]

PHP-FPM was used XDebug and it made the error.

When I turned on debugging the error left and when I turned off debugging the error returned.

[image]

### Solution

To solve the error I disabled XDebug. Also it works when I removed XDebug.

Options to solve the error (one of these):

- **Disable XDebug** (one of these):

  - Set the `XDEBUG_MODE='off'` environment variable.
  - Set `xdebug.mode=off` in `xdebug.ini` or another PHP config.
  - https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#mode
- **Remove XDebug** from your PHP server and restart PHP-FPM (one of these):

  - Remove through PECL (works with Docker): `pecl uninstall xdebug`.
  - Remove through Ubuntu APT: `sudo apt-get purge php-xdebug`.

Restart your PHP-FPM or your service/server.

Answer (score -1):

I did the following to server nginx config:

```
   client_body_timeout 1200;
   client_header_timeout 600;
```

and added zend_extension to php fpm php.ini:

```
zend_extension = xdebug.so
```